# Open (closed) sets of a locally compact space.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ a locally compact space. How do I show that if $A$ is a open (closed) set in $X$ then $A$ is locally compact?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? What have you tried?

Comment: There is no question in the opening post. $\;$

Comment: Alex, I really don't know how to do this. I was thinking in something like:
Once $A$ is open let $\mathbf{B}$ a compact basis. Then you can choose $\mathbf{B}$ open and then $A\cap \mathbf{B}$ is a compact basis for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a closed set in $X$. Let $a \in A$. Now, since $X$ is locally compact, we can find a compact neighborhood $V$ of $a$ in $X$. $V \cap A$ is closed in $V$, and closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

Comment: Nice. How about if $A$ is open?